# insert <thead> in the html using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I insert `<thead>` and `<\thead>` using jQuery?

```
     <table class="Grid">
<!-- insert <thead> -->
                <tr class="GridHeader">
                    <th>BU</th><th>Function</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GridHeader">
                    <th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
    <!-- insert </thead> -->
```

Comment: Pertaining to your update, please reread my answer. It states that you also need to remove and prepend the `<thead>` element for the HTML to be correct.

Comment: For your CSS woes @James123, I suggest opening a new question, as the problems you are experiencing don't really have much to do with your original question now.

Comment: Thanks @FishBasketGordo, Anyway I fixed the CSS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a little tricky, because some browsers will wrap your `<tr>` elements in a `<tbody>` by default if you don't include one yourself. Firefox 19 and Chrome 26 do this. IE 10 does not. Only doing a `wrapAll` will result in the following invalid HTML:

```
<table class="Grid">
    <tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr class="GridHeader">
                <th>BU</th><th>Function</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GridHeader">
                <th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see this behavior for yourself using [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aA6WE/) if you compare the original markup, the markup after clicking Wrap, and the markup after clicking Prepend.

To overcome this, as [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aA6WE/) shows, you need to also remove the newly added `<thead>` and prepend it back to the `<table>`:

```
$('.GridHeader').wrapAll('<thead>');
$('.Grid thead').remove().prependTo('.Grid');
```

Comment: I tried both , did not worked for me. $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.GridHeader').wrapAll('<thead>');
        $('.Grid').dataTable();
    });

Comment: In what way is it not working? The jsfiddle linked to in my answer works on Chrome, Firefox, and IE. Also, as my answer states, only calling `wrapAll` results in invalid markup, so the Data Tables plugin is probably not working because of that. Of course, it would be better if you didn't need to manipulate the HTML in the first place, but I'm assuming that, because you asked the question, that option isn't available to you.

Comment: Yes, I called   $('.GridHeader').wrapAll('<thead>');$('.Grid thead').remove().prependTo('.Grid');
        $('.Grid').dataTable();

Comment: And you're still experiencing a problem? Here's a jsfiddle with a working example with the Data Tables plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/ndhvn/ (The one I linked before was the wrong one, sorry, so I deleted that comment.)

Answer (score 3):

```
var thead = $("<thead>");
$('.GridHeader').wrapAll(thead);
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll

Comment: You're missing some subtle differences in the way that different browsers render tables if you only do a `wrapAll`. See my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15888164/783175

Comment: I tried both , did not worked for me. $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.GridHeader').wrapAll('<thead>');
        $('.Grid').dataTable();
    });